# How to omit 0 from array of randomly generated numbers using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have done a code where it will generate 7 random numbers from 0 to 49.

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn_generate" onClick="getMyLuckyNumbers()">GENERATE NUMBERS</button>
<div id="display"></div>
```

**JS**

```
function getMyLuckyNumbers() {
for (var allNumbers=[],i=0;i<50;++i) allNumbers[i]=i;

function shuffle(array) {
  var tmp, current, top = array.length;
  if(top) while(--top) {
    current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (top + 1));
    tmp = array[current];
    array[current] = array[top];
    array[top] = tmp;
  }
  return array;
}

allNumbers = shuffle(allNumbers);

var luckyNumbers = "";
var g;

for (g = 0; g < 7; g++) {
    luckyNumbers += allNumbers[g] + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = luckyNumbers;
}
```

I would like to know how I can omit 0?

I attempted two ways, but both failed.

**Attempt 1:**

Changed the `i=0` to `i=1`.

```
for (var allNumbers=[],i=1;i<50;++i) 
  allNumbers[i]=i;
```

This did omit 0 but when 0 was randomly supposed to appear, it shows as undefined.

**Attempt 2:**

I tried to do an if statement.

```
if(allNumbers != 0) {
  allNumbers = shuffle(allNumbers);
}
```

But this still displays 0 if it happens to be randomly generated.

So, how do I omit 0?

Comment: `.push()` your numbers into your array `allNumbers.push(i)` so that numbers are added to the end of the array at each iteration

Comment: could you please write that as an answer, where to put that code?

Comment: I just googled `.push`. That is to add content into the array right, how do I remove 0 from the array?

Comment: Oh I think I got an idea, I can use `splice` to remove 0 from the array and then set that as the new array, that would be right? I don't know, I would like to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with starting `i` from `1` is that the `0th` index will be empty, and so when accessed gives `undefined`.

So, if you want to avoid the number `0`, you can make `i` start at 1, but you would need to change the way you add numbers to your array. Instead of adding your numbers to your array by placing them at a specific index, you can `.push()` them to the end of your array each iteration like so:

```
//                      \/------ start at i = 1, the 1st number to be added to your array
for (var allNumbers=[],i=1;i<50;++i) 
  allNumbers.push(i);
```

This way, you will fill up your array with numbers from `1` to `49` which can them be shuffled.